# If $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is continuous, then $f_n(x) = f(x^n)$ converges uniformly on $[0,a],$ $a < 1$ and $∫_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx \to f(0).$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Given f continues function in [0,1] we define a sequence of functions fn(x) = f(x^n) , given that for every number 0<a<1 the sequence of function is uniformly convergs in [0,a] to f(0) prove that the integral of fn(x) from 0 to 1 is f(0).

So i have tried this :
Since the sequence of function uniformly converges to f(0) in [0,a] for every 0<a<1 , fn(x)uniformly converges in [0,1) , i defined a new sequence of functions Gn(x) = fn(x) for every x in [0,1) , and for x= 1 Gn(1)= f(0) .
So Gn(x) uniformly converges to f(0) , now we can do the limit first then the integral , since the limit equals f(0) , we have now integral of f(0) from 0 to 1 which equals f(0) .

I want to know why my proof is wrong .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @CrSb0001 This is a question from my exam , i want to know why what i wrote is wrong

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference If you could mathjax your question body that would be helpful as well. The reason your proof is wrong is because $f_n(x)$ only uniformly converges in every compact subset of $[0,1)$. $G_n(x)$ pointwise converges to $f(0)$. Is this a Riemann integral or a lebesgue integral?

Comment: For $f(x)=x^2$ the conclusion does not hold.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed Thank you , this is Riemann integral , but if it Gn(x) does not converges uniformly, there is a “problematic “ point y , if we look at the interval [0,y] , the original sequence uniformly converges in this interval , contradiction .

Comment: I didn't see that you redefined $g_n$, but if you do it like that, they aren't continuous anymore. If you look, $f_n(1) = f(1)$ for all $n$. So when you say $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f(0)$, it doesn't in the interval $[0,1]$. You can't change the $f_n$ to $g_n$ and say that the integrals converge to the same thing without justifying it, which you didn't do. As the answer points out, you need to use the fact that $f$ is continuous to establish the limit of $f_n(x) \to f(0)$ for $x < 1$, and use that $f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$ to establish why $|\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx -\int_0^1g_n(x)dx|$ is small

Answer (score 2):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists a $\delta>0$, such that
$$
0\le x <\delta\quad\Longrightarrow\quad |f(x)-f(0)|<\varepsilon.
$$
If $a\in (0,1),\,$ then $a^n\to 0$, and hence there is an $n_0\in\mathbb N$, such that
$$
n\ge n_0 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad 0<a^n<\delta.
$$
Hence, if $n\ge n_0$ and $x\in [0,a],\,$ then $0\le x^n\le a^n<\delta,$ and
$$
|f_n(x)-f(0)|=|f(x^n)-f(0)|<\varepsilon.
$$
Indeed, $f_n|_{[0,a]}\to f(0)$ uniformly.

Next, $\varepsilon>0$, and let $M=\max_{x\in [0,1]} |f(x)|$, and $a\in (0,1),$ such that $M(1-a)<\varepsilon$. Then
$$
\left|\int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx-f(0)\right|\le 
\int_0^1 |f_n(x)-f(0)|\,dx\\=\int_0^a |f_n(x)-f(0)|\,dx+\int_a^1 |f_n(x)-f(0)|\,dx<a\varepsilon+2M(1-a)<(a+1)\varepsilon
$$
for $n\ge n_0$.